# How to create an order using mock object in phpunit in Magento?

Tags: magento2, php, phpunit, mocks

I am preparing phpunit tests. I need to create an order using mocking and that order i need to pass in my function.

Please suggest, How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $orderMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Order::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $orderMock->expects($this->once())->method('getState')->willReturn('pending');

        return $orderMock;
```